# Hadoop Configuration() object not picking up /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm starting an application which loads creates a `new YarnConfiguration()` object.

When I'm running it I'm setting `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to `/etc/hadoop/conf` where the configuration files are.

I'm then starting the application;

`yarn -jar jarname.jar --config.file config/local.properties` and getting the following error;

`INFO: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
Jul 25, 2016 12:33:49 PM org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client handleConnectionFailure
INFO: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)`

So it doesn't seem to be picking up the details of the yarn resource manager which are running on another client.

the `yarn-site.xml` has the correct values in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the shame of how long this took me to spot, incase anyone else has the same problem -

It came down to the `-jar` which was incorrect. The command needed to be `yarn jar` without the hypen.